# What is the exact Juniper and Cisco router per-packet balancing hash algorithm?

Tags: cisco, load-balancing, juniper, hash

Due to [JunOS](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos14.2/topics/concept/policy-per-packet-load-balancing-overview.html) and [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_0s/feature/guide/pplb.html) documentation there is ability to configure hashing algorithm choosing one of the *next-hop from the several multiple equal-cost paths*. There is information about fields that could be used to compute target hash - it could be l3 (including src and dst ips) or l4 (including ports) but there is no any information how exactly (crc, xor, and+xor, etc) this hash sum computed. Is there any standard of this behaviour or this is a proprietary and brand/model dependent?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a document](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/etherchannel/116385-technote-etherchannel-00.html) that explains the algorithm for a Cisco 3750, 4500 and 6500.  It's too long to quote here.